# How to update Blob data in users table?

Tags: 7, entities, users, updating

I am trying to update data filed in users table.

[image]

Please suggest a way how to update this field data with help of query or need to follow some other approach ?

```
$old_user_id = 123;
$new_user_id = 456;

$account_old = user_load($old_user_id);
$account_new = user_load($new_user_id);

if ($account_old && $account_new && !empty($account_old->data['uc_stripe_customer_id'])) {
  user_save($account_new, array('data' => array('uc_stripe_customer_id' => $account_old->data['uc_stripe_customer_id'])));
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this would be a good way to do it. You depending what's currently in the data you might want to merge that with the new data. Easy to remove if that's not important.

```
<?php

$old_user_id = 123;
$new_user_id = 456;

$account_old = user_load($old_user_id);
$account_new = user_load($new_user_id);

// Check to make sure accounts are loaded.
if (empty($account_old) == FALSE && empty($account_new) == FALSE) {

  // make sure account data is populated before trying to act on it.
  if(empty($account_old->data) == FALSE) {

    // unserialize the blob from the user object.
    $account_new_data = unserialize($account_old->data);

    // make sure the key exists. maybe other checks.
    if(array_key_exists('uc_stripe_customer_id', $account_new_data) == TRUE) {

        // merge any existing data with the new data.
        $account_new->data = array_merge($account_new, account_new_data);

        user_save($account_new);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a [serialised PHP array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php).

You would, in my humble opinion, be nuts to try to parse this with SQL.

Use PHP to `unserialize`, make your changes, `serialize` it again, and write the result to the database.

Comment: thanks for your answer, please see updated question, is that approach is correct I want to change uc_stripe_customer_id from old account into new one. Please suggest!

Comment: Yep, looks like that should work at first glance - are you having any trouble with it in particular?

Comment: It's working fine was just not sure that it's right way!